# Why when using replace to replace a string in winedt by another string starting with backslash, the backslash disappear?

Tags: winedt

I have been trying to replace all the strings, `v_b`, with a new string, `\bar{v}`, in Winedt for a latex document. I used the replace function to do this. However, after each replacement, the new text appears as `bar{v}` instead of the desired `\bar{v}`. How should I fix this?

Comment: I can't test this because I don't have WinEdt and am not on Windows, so I can't install it, but a lot of regex notations for find/replace use backslashes to escape things, so it itself must be escaped when it is used literally; so try two backslashes `\\ `.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. In the WinEdt replacement dialogue box, you should be able to check and uncheck whether regular-expression syntax should apply to the search-and-replace operation.